# How many n satisfy this matrix equation?

Tags: matrices

$A = \begin{pmatrix}
 0&1  &2 \\ 
 0&0  & 1\\ 
 0& 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$
How many n is exist so that $X^{n} = A$?

I can see some characteristics:

det(X) = $0$

$X^{3n} = 0 I$

But not sure how does this help. And, of course, n can not be 0, but can always be 1.

Comment: not actually difficult: if there is some $n \geq 2$ and an $X$ with $X^n = A,$  one thing we know is that $XA=AX .$  If you write down a matrix $X$ with 9 letters as elements, commutation shows that $X$ is upper triangular, of a certain pattern. Then $X^2=A$ or $X^3=A$  impose further conditions....

Comment: You say XA = AX. Why? I see that X be upper triangular implies this, but you said it before conclude that X is upper triangular, so how to know that the matrices commute?

Comment: if $X^n = A$ you have $XA = X X^n = X^{n+1} = X^n X = AX.$ It comes from the associative law.

Comment: anyway, write $$ X = \left( \begin{array}{ccc} b&c&d\\ e&f&g \\ h&i&j  \end{array} \right) $$  and compare $XA$ with $AX$

Comment: Here's another approach: $A$ is nilpotent (indeed $A^m = 0 \iff m \ge 3$), hence so must be $X$. What do you know about $3 \times 3$ nilpotent matrices?